# Connecting to ODBC on VM with c#/asp.net from outside the VM

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc, quickbooks

The goal, through c# using asp.net, is to accomplish the following:

1. Make connection to VM server
2. Connect to a sql tool known as "Database Browser" through an ODBC - database browser is essentially a knockoff of SQL Server
3. Return data from QuickBooks (currently connected to "Database Browser") - results can be returned to a console for testing purposes for now but will eventually need to function within a web application

Details: I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have heard mixed opinions about whether this could/should be done by connecting from outside of the VM vs Visual Studio needing to be installed on the VM itself.

I will be happy to provide more info as necessary if this was unclear as I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Check out [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for details on how to ask good questions and what type of questions to ask.  Please include any code you have and try to be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish for a start.

Comment: Tim, thanks you for the reply.  Think I'll need to go back into the assignment and look for more specific questions...thank you for your feedback